# How to identify the fabric-protos version used to generate specific fabric-protos-go

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

`github.com/hyperledger/fabric` makes use of `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go` repo as a dependency module to setup gRPC communication between nodes. These `fabric-protos-go` files are generated by `.proto` of `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos` repo.

I have cloned `github.com/hyperledger/fabric` `Tag:v2.4.7` repo and making some updates on it. I need to generate some go structs to use by defining new `message` in `.proto` files.

This `fabric-v2.4.7` depends on `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go v0.0.0-20220315113721-7dc293e117f7` as per the go.mod

But I am not able to identify which version of `fabric-protos` led to generation this `fabric-protos-go v0.0.0-20220315113721-7dc293e117f7`. Because if I clone the the latest version of `fabric-protos` repo to generate go files and use as dependency its throwing many incompatibility errors.

Please let me know how can I determine which version of `fabric-protos-go` and `fabric-protos` were used in a specific `fabric` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This documentation page for fabric-protos mentions which versions of the protocol buffer bindings correspond to which Fabric versions:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-protos/

The protocol buffer definition files are in branches of the [fabric-protos repository](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos), named the same as the versions in the documentation page above. Currently the **main** branch contains the definitions for Fabric v3 (the v0.3.x versions of the published bindings).

If you are making modifications, you should just pick the HEAD (latest commit) of the appropriate branch on which to base your change. Avoid making breaking changes. Changes will also need to be applied to any more recent versions (branches) so compatibility is maintained going forwards. A good strategy if you actually come to push changes to the repository is probably to raise a pull request for the main branch first, then cherry-pick changes back to as many earlier version branches as you need.